# How to get input from user when connecting to remote servers? [Python]

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I need to connect to a remote server using a (non-python) script from terminal.

```
$./myscript <parameters>
```

Normally, I would need to enter the password. I have the following question, assuming a python script will run `myscript`:

1. How do I get the password from the user
2. How do I feed it into `myscript`?

Comment: If the script is running locally, then you can get the password from the user the same way you would for any local program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you would probably use the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) function.

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
print 'You entered:', password
```

The major advantage is that the password will not be visible on the screen as the user enters it.

If you simply want to pass in arguments to your application you can use sys.argv.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print "First argument:", sys.argv[1]
```

If you need to pass on a password to a script executed by Python you can use subprocess call.

```
import getpass
import subprocess

password = getpass.getpass()
subprocess.call(["myscript", password ])
```

Comment: will there be a conflict with the command python is running? and how do I feed it back to the script run underneath?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your problem. Could you expand on the questions?

Comment: no, python is calling "myscript" which requires password

Comment: @Bob I updated my answer, was it something like that you were looking for?

Comment: @Bob I tested it with a realm simple example and it worked fine. Can you be more specific on what isn't working? Is it not getting the password?

Comment: it looks like it uses the password in the wrong way. If I don't add the password, it works just fine

Comment: Update your question and show a real world example instead of myscript <parameter>